# Enter Vr-mode in an iframe (ios)

Tags: ios, iphone, iframe, fullscreen, aframe

I have an iframe with my a-scene loaded inside. My Problem is on my iphone i can´t enter the vr-mode. It goes to his stereoscopic view but inside the iframe not fullscreen. Some ideas how to fix this=?

My iframe-tag looks like this:

```
<iframe src="a-scene.html" allowfullscreen allowvr="yes"></iframe>
```

By the way on Android it goes to fullscreen.

Here you can watch my hole project (vid/pic are just placeholder):

https://needsomehelp.glitch.me/

https://glitch.com/~needsomehelp

Comment: this problem is still active, someone with an idea or an workaround feel free to speak :)

Comment: i still have this damn problem i try follow the instructions here https://github.com/immersive-web/cardboard-vr-display but it don´t work :/